# How to use a character as a separator in a string

Tags: java, android

I get a response back from the server like this :  "Username|Name|AccountType|Organization".
Is there a way to use the "|'s" as separators and get each variable separately. I'm guessing I would have to use a for loop.

Comment: If an answer is correct, you should accept it using the tick mark next to it (that's how this site works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just like you would any other `String.split`.

Here is a quick ex:

```
public class Stack
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String test = "Username|Name|AccountType|Organization";
    String[] token = test.split("\\|");

    System.out.println(test);
    System.out.println();

    for(int i=0; i<token.length; i++)
    System.out.println(token[i]);

    System.out.println();
}
}
```

The output would be the following;

```
Username|Name|AccountType|Organization

Username
Name
AccountType
Organization
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use `String.split` with `|` . It will return a `String[]` array. For instance

```
String test = "Username|Name|AccountType|Organization";
for (String token :  test.split("\\|")) {
     Log.i("TEST", token);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Guava's Splitter class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

```
List<String> tokens = Splitter.on("|").split("Username|Name|AccountType|Organization");
```

With [Apache Commons' StringUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String,%20char)):

```
String[] tokens = StringUtils.split("Username|Name|AccountType|Organization", '|');
```

And [plain Java Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String[] test = "Username|Name|AccountType|Organization".split("\\|");
```

PS: no you don't need Guava or Apache Commons just to split a string. But they bring in a lot of really useful stuff that will make your code more robust. Guava is one of the libraries I include in any project.